# Typescript generated code fails to run due to amdefine

Tags: node.js, typescript, amd

I'm writing a NodeJS app, using v10.8.0 and Typescript 3.2.1

TS generates JS code fine, but the code cannot be executed because of the following error:

**amdefine with no module ID cannot be called more than once per file**

I can see the error comes from the amdefine package, but it is actually triggered by other packages which seem to use AMD modules.

I know that adding something like this to the problematic code solves the issue:

```
  if (typeof define !== 'function') {
    var define = require('amdefine')(module)
}
```

but I obviously cannot edit 3rd party code..

Is there a better way to make Node work with AMD modules?

TS target is ES2016 and it uses commonjs modules. This worked fine before. But now that I have these AMD based dependencies, everything is broken.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Amdefine has a intercept feature which adds the above code to all AMD modules automatically. This is experimental, but it seems to work.

```
require('amdefine/intercept');
```

More info on this [here](https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine)